# How to link bootstrap styles in jsp

Tags: jsp, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap folders in my project

src/main/resources/css

How should I include it on jsp to get this styles available?

Comment: the same way you call all other css files u have in your project. If you have a jsp that will be included as header in all pages, you just go there and call <link rel="stylesheet" href="../pathToTheCSS"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Maven and use a web application, you should put them in your `src/main/webapp` directory.

The `src/main/resources` will be mapped on the `WEB-INF/classes` folder, which is unaccessible from outside (anything in the `WEB-INF` folder is).

If you put it in the `src/main/webapp` folder, you can retrieve it by:

```
http://<servername>:<portname>/<context root>/css/...
```

But you probably don't need the servername/portname because you can also work with absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way i solved this problem. I did lot of research about this. IDK whether it's good or bad practice but it saved me lot of time. Before you use the bootstrap or js make sure you put all your css and js file into one folder under the resources folder. Reason is lot of time if we use spring annotation, we should use exact same hierarchy in the spring.

In the dispatcher-servlet.xml use this line

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/theme1" cache-period="31556926"/>
```

in your jsp file use this line to add the css(i added my css file under this location 
 webApp/resources/theme1/css)

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/carousel.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Also add these dependency in your pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/taglibs/standard -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```